# Errors and Warnings when installing Scrapy with pip on OSX

Tags: python, macos, terminal, scrapy, pip

I want to install Scrapy on my macbook OSX 10.9

I followed all of the prerequisites listed here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html

And then typed the following into the terminal: `pip install Scrapy`

At the very bottom of the terminal it says:

```
2 warnings and 6 errors generated.

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

And then below that it says:

```
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/sj/fs5lzbyd7p37_jdkqw03_q4c0000gn/T/pip_build_johnmosely/Twisted/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/sj/fs5lzbyd7p37_jdkqw03_q4c0000gn/T/pip-lkdl1g-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/sj/fs5lzbyd7p37_jdkqw03_q4c0000gn/T/pip_build_johnmosely/Twisted
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/johnmosely/.pip/pip.log
```

I went and looked and there is now a folder on my macbook called "Scrapy" and it contains a zip file called "scrapy-scrapy-0.22.0-7-gcde9a8c.zip" but that's it so I'm assuming that it was not installed successfully?

Or should I just ignore the errors and warnings and unzip the zip file?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: I know for a fact it's not installed because when I try to start a new scrapy project the terminal gives me this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/scrapy", line 3, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from twisted import version as _txv
ImportError: No module named 'twisted'
```

EDIT 2 - Here are the 6 errors that were printed:

```
^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
twisted/python/sendmsg.c:129:9: error: non-void function 'initsendmsg' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
        return;
        ^
twisted/python/sendmsg.c:138:9: error: non-void function 'initsendmsg' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
        return;
        ^
twisted/python/sendmsg.c:145:9: error: non-void function 'initsendmsg' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
        return;
        ^
twisted/python/sendmsg.c:159:9: error: non-void function 'initsendmsg' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
        return;
        ^
twisted/python/sendmsg.c:165:9: error: non-void function 'initsendmsg' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
        return;
        ^
twisted/python/sendmsg.c:170:9: error: non-void function 'initsendmsg' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
        return;
```

Comment: Can you add the 6 errors that were printed?

Comment: I just added the errors for you in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Scrapy doesn't support Python 3 yet - porting is not started because of twisted issues. Scrapy 0.22 only works with Python 2.7.

Comment: I am trying to install it using python 2.7 and it still will not work. Any chance we can continue this discussion in chat ?

Comment: When I type "python" into terminal it says python 2.7.5 which means my default system version is 2.7.5 correct? Then how come whenever i try doing "pip install scrapy" or "pip install twisted" it constantly refers to Python version 3.3 in the terminal output?

Comment: The best way to deal with such issues is to create a virtualenv.

Comment: Yes I have and that still doesn't work. When I type "virtualenv ENV" into the terminal this is what it outputs: Using base prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3'
New python executable in ENV5/bin/python3
Also creating executable in ENV5/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.

Comment: ^^ Am I correct in assuming that it's still trying to use version 3.3 when I need to use version 2.7.5?

Comment: Yes, it's using Python 3. You may try running `virtualenv  -p python2.7 ENV`.

Comment: Yes I have tried "virtualenv -p python2.7 ENV" several times now. When I enter that all throughout the terminal output it references python version 3.3 so it still wants to use it. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure the virtualenv is activated?

Comment: Even after I do the virtualenv look at the first line the terminal outputs when i try to install scrapy with pip: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrapy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages

Comment: Yes I am because after I enter the virtualenv code you provided it outputs this: Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7
New python executable in env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.

Comment: This means virtualenv is created, not activated (unless you also ran 'source ENV/bin/activate').

Comment: I got it to work! After creating the virtual environment I was using "pip install scrapy" when I should have been entering in "ENV/bin/pip install scrapy"

Answer (score 2):

Scrapy needs twisted to work and it is trying to compile it but runnning into errors. I have found [bug tracker for this here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6540). That bug is still open as far as I can see, so on Python 3.3 it is not possible to install twisted right now. You might like to try installing it with Python 2.7.

Comment: That's weird because I actually already have xcode 5.0.2 installed and use it all the time. If I understand you correctly, that would mean that I already DO have clang installed correct?

Comment: What happens when you try to run clang yourself from the command line? You need xcode command line tools too.

Comment: Sorry I rarely use the terminal. I just did "xcode-select --install" and installed the command line tools and it said they successfully installed, but then I just tried installing scrapy again and it is still giving the same errors.

Comment: Something is not right with your answer because if I go to file:///Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ clang is listed there.

Comment: Well that's not `/usr/bin/clang` is it? Can you run `/usr/bin/clang` which is needed by Scrapy?

Comment: If I enter "/usr/bin/clang" in the terminal it outputs "clang: error: no input files".

Comment: I'm sorry, I read your error message as if the command was missing when it clearly was saying some libraries were not found probably. So clang is installed, there's a problem with dependency.

Comment: "there's a problem with dependency" - Sorry, I don't understand what that means.

Comment: I get the same problem when I try to install Twisted with pip. Also, none of my command line tools show up in the xcode preferences it sounds like some other people are having the same problem and it's specific to xcode 5.0.2 or mavericks but I still can't find a solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46615/discussion-between-tayfun-and-user3117509)

Answer (score 0):

To successfully install Scrapy, you need to make sure that you have already installed the tool Twisted.

I met the same problem,"error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1" , when I tried to install Scrapy and Twisted in my mac.

This problem was fixed after I installed the Xcode. I'm not sure if you use MacOS system like me. If yes, this may help you.

command line:

```
xcode-select --install
```